# Swift ios store Data and String in Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tuples

I wonder if its possible to store both Data and String in a array?
I need a way to store images that user picks together with the image names inside a array so I later can append it to my API request when I upload it.

Now I am using a array tuple that I later append Data and String to

```
var imgArray = [(Data, String)]()
```

Then I add data to that array tuple like this:

```
if let firstImage = self.firstImage {
                if let firstImageData = firstImage.compressImage() {
                    self.imgArray.append(firstImageData, self.randomImageName(length: 15))
                }
```

I use the code above for everyimage the user uploads and it works, `imgArray` gets populated with both Data and String which I later send to my API.

But is there a way to use a array to store Data and String values to?

I am not sure if tuples is the best solution
            }

Comment: If the Strings can be made unique, then a Dictionary might be the way to go. How are you pulling the Strings and Data out of the array?

Comment: @BallpointBen Eg pulling strings out: ``parameters["images"] = imgArray.map{$0.1}``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple discourages from using tuples as data source.

> Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They are not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple

---

The (object oriented) Swift way is a struct:

```
struct ImageData {
    var data : Data
    var name : String
}
```

---

```
var imgArray = [ImageData]()
```

---

```
if let firstImage = self.firstImage {
    if let firstImageData = firstImage.compressImage() {
       self.imgArray.append(ImageData(data:firstImageData, name:self.randomImageName(length: 15))
     }
```

The benefit is to get the members by name

```
let imageName = imgArray[0].name
```

Comment: Great answer and a great example. But I only use my tuple above for a uploading form for blog posts. The user enters some text and adds a few images then presses upload and its done. Doesnt this count as a "temporary groups of related values"

Comment: Of course you can use a tuple, the Apple statement is more a suggestion than a necessity. However I'd prefer a struct also for better readability of the code.